# How to extend a YAML stylelint configuration up the directory tree (what ESLint does automatically)?

Tags: stylelint

I have a root `.stylelintrc` file (in YAML format) which has my main configuration. I want to override some of those rules for files in a specific directory, how do I do that? In ESLint I could just create an `.eslintrc` file in that directory and it would magically happen.

I tried using `extends`, but I'm not sure if that works for YAML format.

Comment: `extends` should work in YAML format. And this is one of the main use-cases for `extends`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in your nested `.stylelintrc` you can just do:

```
extends: ../path/to/.stylelintrc
rules:
  ...
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `.stylelintrc` here?